# Pandas: Splitting a column by delimiter and re-arrenging based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by, split

Let `df` be a data frame.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Home', 'Score', 'Away'])
   ...: df.loc[0] = ['Team A', '3-1', 'Team B']
   ...: df.loc[1] = ['Team B', '2-1', 'Team A']
   ...: df.loc[2] = ['Team B', '2-2', 'Team A']
   ...: df.loc[3] = ['Team A', '0-1', 'Team B']

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
     Home Score    Away
0  Team A   3-1  Team B
1  Team B   2-1  Team A
2  Team B   2-2  Team A
3  Team A   0-1  Team B
```

I want to make `df_1` out of `df`.

```
In [4]: df_1
Out[4]:
  Team A Team B
0      3      1
1      1      2
2      2      2
3      0      1
```

What is the easiest way?

As a beginner, I can split the `'Score'` column into two columns and then loop over the other columns and get `df_1`, but I guess there should be an easier way of doing that, probably with a `lambda` function or `group_by` method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df["values"] = df.apply(lambda row: {row["Home"]:row["Score"].split("-")[0], row["Away"]:row["Score"].split("-")[1]}, axis=1)

output_df = pd.DataFrame(df["values"].tolist())
```

Output:

```
    Team A  Team B
0   3   1
1   1   2
2   2   2
3   0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is just two teams, we can revert the score if needed.

Where functions in the following way, if the condition is true, it keeps original value. If not, it can call input value from a list of values. Our condition is on the team and mapper is a reversal of a string.

```
l_rev_string = lambda s: s[::-1]

df_score_rev = df.Score.apply(l_rev_string)

df1 = df.Score.where(df.Home == 'Team A', df_score_rev)\
    .str.split('-',expand=True)\
    .rename(columns = {0:'Team A',1:'Team B'})
```

```
|    |   Team A |   Team B |
|---:|---------:|---------:|
|  0 |        3 |        1 |
|  1 |        1 |        2 |
|  2 |        2 |        2 |
|  3 |        0 |        1 |
```

Comment: The approach is interesting but the final result is not correct. It does not reverse the second row and instead of, for example, giving [1, 2, 2, 1] for Team B, it gives [1, 1, 2, 1] (shown as Team A in your output).

Comment: Sorry, I had two versions: one with lambda inputted and one with reversal first. It seems that the callable does not work for some reason, I edited it to a version where you reverse everything and the cherry-pick the right ones.